# Swift 3, highlight word when spoken in AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: ios, swift, text, highlighting

Trying to highlight a word during an AVSpeechSynthesizer action. Text is spoken but the word is not highlighted. The text is contained in a text view `infoTxt` in `func speechSynthesizer()`.

Still have to work out how to un-highlight after being spoken.

```
@IBAction func ReadText(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if !self.synth.isSpeaking  {

        let textParagraphs = self.infoTxt.text.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        self.totalUtterance = textParagraphs.count

        for pieceOfText in textParagraphs {

            let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: pieceOfText)

            let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en GB")
            speechUtterance.voice = voice
            _ = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
            self.synth.speak(speechUtterance)
        }


        func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
            let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: utterance.speechString)
            mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: characterRange)

            infoTxt.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
        }
    }else {
        self.synth.continueSpeaking()
    }

    myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: infoTxt.text)
    myUtterance.rate = 0.1
    _ = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice()
    synth.speak(myUtterance)
    _ = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "Tom")
}

@IBAction func PauseText(_ sender: Any) {
    self.synth.pauseSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.word)
}

@IBAction func StopText(_ sender: Any) {
    self.synth.stopSpeaking(at: AVSpeechBoundary.immediate)
}
```

Comment: Did you set delegate?

Comment: Yesclass ViewController: UIViewController, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate

Comment: No, I mean something like `my.synth.delegate = self`

Comment: Hi jokeman  I think so:  let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
                                      var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")

Answer (score 0):

Following @jokeman clear comment but including an example in Swift 3 syntax

Add a label to a view and make it available

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblExerciseMessage: UILabel!
```

Init speechengine in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear for an example

```
let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().first(where: { $0.name == "Samantha" })

let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

synth.delegate = self as? AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate //Set the delegate. No need to type it; just for highlighting

let utter = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Dear Coder, please use google to find the answers. smiley ")
 utter.voice = voice

synth.speak(utter)
```

And then the called by delegate function : speechSynthesizer and populating the Label reference

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {

    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: utterance.speechString)
    mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range:  NSMakeRange(0, (utterance.speechString as! NSString).length))
    mutableAttributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: characterRange)
    lblExerciseMessage.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
    print (mutableAttributedString) //debug message
}
```